# Expose a Component and Mock within the same NgModule

Tags: angular

Let's say that I have a an `@NgModule` that looks something like this:

```
    @NgModule({
      declarations: [
        ...
        MyComponent,
        MyComponentMock
      ],
      imports: [
       ...
      ],
      exports: [
        ...
        MyComponent,
        MyComponentMock
      ],
      ...
    })
```

where

```
    @Component({
      selector: 'my-comp',
      ...
    })
    export class MyComponent { ... }
```

and

```
    @Component({
        selector: 'my-comp-mock',
        ...
    })
    export class MyComponentMock {
    }
```

Within an Angular SPA that consumes this library/module, I clearly want to

- Use `MyComponent` within parent components within the SPA
- Use `MyComponentMock` within tests that consume `MyComponent` within the
  SPA

I know that I can create `MyComponentMock` within the SPA locally and mock `MyComponent` and get the tests for the parent component in the SPA to pass.

Is there a way that I can selectively replace `MyComponent` with `MyComponentMock` in the parent component SPA tests?  Can I selectively replace/update the `my-comp` with `my-comp-mock`, or use `TestBed.overrideComponent`?

I can't find any good examples to do this, and when I do, not all the tests pass.

Is this even allowed?

Comment: Use `TestBed.configureTestingModule({declarations: [MyComponentMock]})` in your  tests.

Comment: This will not work if I import it from the library.  This syntax only works if the mock is in the SPA.

Comment: Define a new `TestModule` that declares `MyComponentMock` with `my-comp` selector and use this module only in tests: TestBed.configureTestingModule({imports: [TestModule]})

Comment: How can I do that from within a library?.  Two components will have the same selector (`my-comp`) and Angular won't be able to resolve that.